# Turn off one-digit Alt codes

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, alt-code

On Windows 10, when I type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad1</kbd> it enters ☺ at the cursor. While I realize that this is [an old function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_code) I would very much like to turn it off. I have no conceivable use for typing ☺, and it seems wasteful to lose so many useful shortcuts to something so trivial.

**Is there any way to disable single-digit Alt codes for symbols such as (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad1</kbd>: ☺, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad3</kbd>: ♥, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad7</kbd>: ◘) in order to use these as keyboard shortcuts instead?**

Motivation: The numpad provides a very tempting set of options for assigning shortcuts in applications that allow modification of keyboard shortcuts. For example, I am running Rstudio Server inside Google Chrome, so I have a tabbed application inside of a tabbed browser, making Alt an attractive choice for shortcuts to navigate within Rstudio Server; the large number of panels make the numpad a great choice for navigating to panels.

Comment: Yes, and four-digit Alt codes like ALT-0169 make sense. But why are Alt-1 to Alt-9 assigned to such useless purposes?

Comment: because 1-31 are perfectly valid ASCII codes, and it just happens that on code page 437, code 1 is the smiley, and code 2 the inverted smiley etc. Simply use Shift+Numpad keys or Ctrl+Numpad keys offer loads of other possible shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

Upon @xypha's advice I asked the question to `AutoHotKey` specialists.

On [autohotkey.com](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=76&t=113741&e=1&view=unread#unread) was suggested to me the following script, which works like a charm.

Note however, it fails **in Notepad**; it will work only once. Afterwards all combinations will be disabled.

```
$!Numpad1::
$!Numpad2::
$!Numpad3::
$!Numpad4::
$!Numpad5::
$!Numpad6::
$!Numpad7::
$!Numpad8::
$!Numpad9::
$!Numpad0::Numpads .= "{" SubStr(A_ThisHotkey, 3) "}"
~LAlt Up::
IF StrLen(Numpads) > 9
    Send, {LAlt Down}%Numpads%{LAlt Up}
Numpads =
Return
```

Answer (score 1):

[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/download/) can help turn off <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Numpad</kbd> keys or remap them to a more useful purpose.

- Install AutoHotkey or extract the portable app to suitable location
- Create an AHK file (I usually go to Desktop > Right click > New > AutoHotkey Script)
- Modify the following lines as needed (in AHK v1) and add to AHK file

```
; lines beginning with semicolon (;) and characters appearing after a semicolon are considered as comments and are not executed
; some common key modifiers are ! for ALT, ^ for CTRL, # for WIN, + for SHIFT
; "!" modifier applies to any type of ALT key. For more specific remaps 
;   >!    is RAlt / right ALT
;   <!    is LAlt / left ALT
;   <^>!  is ALTGr (LControl & RAlt)

; Examples - 

!Numpad1::Return      ; = do nothing ; "return" disables the key combo
!Numpad2::Send ^{Tab} ; = CTRL + Tab = switch tabs in a browser ; Send simulates key presses
```

- Save the AHK file and run it in one of the following ways -

  - Move the file or create a shortcut to the file in startup folder `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`, so that your remapped key are enabled every time you login, or
  - Create a new task in **Task Scheduler** for more customized triggers, or
  - Run the AHK file manually by double clicking on it whenever you need it.
    I am not familiar with Rstudio. See [AutoHotkey help](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/AutoHotkey.htm) for more information on how to remap and change the AHK file to suit your needs.

For additional software recommendations, post a question on SE's [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) website.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the free [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

The following example script will intercept the Windows
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad1</kbd> and will send instead
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>
to the active window:

```
!Numpad1::Send, !1
```

You may add more lines to the script for the other Numpad keys.
You may also limit its actions to specific executables.

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and
double-click it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on
the green H icon in the traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login,
place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)

Comment: God bless you, I've been looking for an answer to this for years, it's almost 2 or 3 years since this problem started in Windows 11, and I have finally got it fixed. This is the right solution for this problem, it doesn't print annoying emojis and the keyboard shortcuts alt+0-9 are still working. I'm using these keyboard shortcuts for other things, and whenever I pressed it it printed emoji to the editor. Thank you , I'm super happy about this.

Comment: So it's not perfect, all other alt codes stopped working, eg. I can't write alt+0244 or alt+0228 anymore. The fix for this doesn't look simple, it should detect subsequential keypresses I think. At least would be good to know how to skip the above workaround for some alt code.

Comment: @SilverZachara: alt+0244 works for me with this script. AHK alone cannot explain such a problem.