# "Alt + 1-digit" symbol appearing subsequently to AltGr combination

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, keyboard-layout, alt-code

I'm under Windows 11, French layout, and the issue occurs in editors such as Word or TexStudio.

When I combine <kbd>AltGr</kbd> with a key of the top line, trying to type <kbd>[</kbd> or <kbd>]</kbd> or <kbd>\</kbd>, the right symbol appears and, just after, I get the parasitic <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0-9</kbd> (single digit) symbol replacement such as a ♠ (spade), a ♥ (heart), a ☺ (smiley).

This happens regardless of the keyboard (happens on different laptops too), and regardless of any so-called "3rd-party" softwares running in the background.

This is by far the weirdest Windows bug I have ever had (and I've had some, believe me).

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: AltGr with `[]` works fine with a French keyboard layout. If this is an AHK problem, you need to add the `.ahk` file to your post.

Comment: No, i'm not using ahk, basically. The issue is random and it began happening when new 1-digit shortcuts were introduced in recent Windows versions.

Comment: related discussion - https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?p=507167#p507167

Comment: linked Q&A - https://superuser.com/a/1764765/391770

Comment: The Windows keyboard should not do that. It's probably some third-party product.

Comment: @harrymc I don't use 3rd party programs for input. I thought about the keyboard software, but then, how come the problem also occurs on my laptop? It's a bloody Windows bug.

Comment: I disagree. Millions of French use this keyboard daily without such problems. I suggest to look into *Control Panel > Programs and Features* and perhaps the more detailed [Autoruns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns).

Comment: @harrymc How do you know? Maybe they just don't care. I know my installed programs and autorun registry keys. It's pretty random, so it's difficult to reproduce.

Comment: @harrymc Also, "millions of French" don't use backslashes and braces, or very marginally. Only programmers, especially LaTeX typesetters, actually use those symbols extensively enough to observe the bug (as it is random) and be bothered by it.